# Getting facebook access token in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();

dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
      client_id = "MyAppId",
      client_secret = "MyAppSecret",
      redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
      code = "code"
});

fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

I use this piece of code to get facebook access token. When I try to login with any account, there is no problem. However, if I try to post something on that account's wall, I get an error which is;

> (OAuthException-#200)(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application
>   to perform this action.

Also I want to add that if I get the access token from graph api explorer in developers.facebook.com manually and use it in my code as access token, I can post.

P.S: I gave "publish_actions" permission to the account and nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your have requested permissions using /{user-id}/permissions ?

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4 for details.

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_photos",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_actions",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}

these are the permissions. As I stated above, if I get token from graph api explorer with this permissions, I can post. But if I use the code I wrote, I cannot post, it gives that error.